# Нахождение данных в тексте Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет, пишу бота для ВК, но суть вопроса не в этом, я получаю данные от ВК в таком виде:

```
response { count: 551743,
  items:
   [ { id: 456802410,
       album_id: 254298219,
       owner_id: -160072015,
       user_id: 100,
       photo_75: 'https://pp.userapi.com/c847122/v847122497/72534/ziUiByb4IEY.jpg',
       photo_130: 'https://pp.userapi.com/c847122/v847122497/72535/DFSD5-c8VEo.jpg',
       photo_604: 'https://pp.userapi.com/c847122/v847122497/72536/IHs7HDbPzlM.jpg',
       photo_807: 'https://pp.userapi.com/c847122/v847122497/72537/bqgWQ0d8L-M.jpg',
       width: 502,
       height: 758,
       text: 'ABCD',
       date: 1528491239 }
```

Как сделать чтобы программа среди текста находила значение `owner_id`? (Не сам `owner_id`, а числа, находящиеся в нем)
Заранее спасибо

Comment: а причем тут Java?

Comment: Случайно не тот тег поставил

Comment: `owner_id` какой именно записи из ~552 тысяч? И почитайте на всякий случай это: https://vk.com/dev/execute

Comment: Попробуйте так: `console.log(response.items[номер].owner_id);`

Comment: "[номер]" это что?

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев у вас может быть `count: 551743,` результатов, полагаю, нужно выбрать только 1. Параметр `items:` содержит массив, а значит там много других элементов которые пронумерованы начиная с нуля.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все заработало :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как комментарий помог переношу из комментариев в ответ.

У вас может быть `count: 551743,` результатов, полагаю, нужно выбрать только 1. Параметр `items:` содержит массив, а значит там много других элементов которые пронумерованы начиная с нуля.

Попробуйте так: `console.log(response.items[номер].owner_id);`